# twitter-bootstrap 'disabled' class not working on ie9

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-9

Using bootstrap, when you add **'.disabled'** class to a button, it changes its **opacity** and **disable button click**.

This is working on current versions of Chrome and Firefox.

On **Internet Explorer 9**, I'm getting the button to change its opacity, but when I **click it**, it **submits** my form (although cursor icon changes to a prohibition sign).

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Can you please inspect if disabled="disabled" is added in HTML after you add the .disabled class?

Comment: disabled="disabled" is not added, but on Chrome/Firefox it isn't added either, and it works there. I think it has something to do with the way IE9 implements (or not) pointer-event: shttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Answer (score 6):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary disabled" 
   disabled="disabled">Primary button</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-large" disabled>Button</button>
```

I tried using the above buttons works fine for me in all the browsers.

Note:

```
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-primary disabled">Primary link</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-large disabled">Link</a>
```

Use disabled class in case of links.

Cheers!!!

Comment: Effectively, adding disable="disabled" works (is what I ended up doing). But my intention was to find out a way to make IE9 disable mouse event when .disabled class is added to an element (like Chrome/Firefox do)

Comment: Hi canotto90, In my firefox(V 25.0) and chrome(V 30.0.1.) browsers I found on adding the class disabled it didn't disable the mouse event, it only added a CSS class that caused the decrease in opacity. But the button was still clickable in all the browsers.

Comment: Hi Amit, were you including twitter-bootstrap js and css when you tested it? I think they are somehow disabling mouse click

Comment: Yes, I included jquery.js , bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js files while testing..

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been asked long time ago but I have ran into the same issue.

This won't work under IE < 11 because Bootstrap is using "pointer-events" css property which is not supported by IE 10 and earlier. ([Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events)).

I came up with this simple JS for buttons:

```
$('button.disabled').prop('disabled', true);
```

for links:

```
$('a.disabled').click(function(){
       $(this).preventDefault();
});
```

I've hope that helps.

Comment: This won't work in IE8. For IE8< use event.returnValue = false;